# Syntax error while converting varchar to numeric in sql

Tags: sql

I want to convert a varchar to numeric, I looked aroud and found SELECT CAST. I tried to use it like this this:

```
SELECT CAST(`Elo` AS INT) FROM Table `Rankings`;
```

However, I get a syntax error. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: which db? what syntax error?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the Table keyword from your query.

```
SELECT CAST(`Elo` AS INT) FROM `Rankings`;
```

Comment: I put SELECT CAST(`Elo` AS INT) FROM `Rankings`; but I still get the syntax error message.

Comment: If you don't tell which db you are using..  It'll be difficult to help you.

Comment: I'm using a table called Rankings. As for the database, I'm using a database called Proyect.

Comment: I asked about db engine.